# VBA - conditional formatting with text

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I was hoping that there is a way to conditionally format the `column G` like `columns B & C`.  Possibly as binary, where the text  = 1 and blank = 0?  Thanks in advance.  [image: range]

Comment: Unfortunately, icon sets only do work with values. There are some "dirty" ways to still get it the way you want, but right now it is not clear how your worksheet is set up. If the text is made by a formula (so you only have this text or nothing) you could set up the number formatting to `"FAIL - Check Output",,,@` this way, all positive values are shown as exactly this text (text stays untouched and negative numbers/zero will show an empty cell). Now your formula outputs `1` for fail and `0` for ok and this way it can be used with icon sets...

Comment: You could use a separate column for your icons and set up a numeric formula there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly know the logic but here is a way to accomplish this with tweaking `Custom Number Format`.  Here is the example and how I do it:

1. Determine your logic.  See what I have in my example.  I simply used 0 and 1 because `Conditional Formatting` works better with numbers.

[image]

2. Right click on the cell on column G, make a rule like **`[=0]"FAIL";[=1]"OKAY"`**.  Values inside [ ] is the condition, and the output string is inside the double quotes " ".

[image]

As for the `Conditional Formatting`, I believe you know what to do.  Please let me know if this helps and good luck.